# Adding more directory to user selected directory

Tags: c#, process

So, as of right now I have a start process fully working

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = textBox1.Text;
    startInfo.Arguments = @"-window -useBE -mod=e:\Aaron\Addons\";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

But I want other users to have it work for them too. But in `startInfo.Arguments` I have a directory `e:\Aaron...`
I already have a textbox that would display the directory of the user.
So that directory would have to replace everything after `-mod=`
But the tricky part is that after that directory I would need another folder that the user has in that directory. So I would basically have to add \ExtraFolder to that directory.
So in the end it would become `startInfo.Arguments = @"-window -useBE -mod= //user input directory\@CBA_A3";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to inject the user's directory path?  Just do this:

```
startInfo.Arguments = 
    string.Format(@"-window -useBE -mod={0}\@CBA_A3", userPathSegment);
```

Comment: One second, let me try it out.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks alot buddy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# 6.0, you can take advantage of string interpolation:

```
startInfo.Arguments = $"-window -useBE -mod={yourInputTextBox.Text}";
```

Obviously you'd need to change the reference within the curly braces to match your actual program.